# Why does the Apache Camel route subscriber suddenly quit receiving messages from Quarkus publisher app?

Tags: java-8, apache-camel, amqp, activemq-artemis, quarkus

***QUESTION:***

*Why does the Apache Camel route subscriber suddenly quit receiving messages from Quarkus publisher app, although the Quarkus publisher continues to publish?
--Is there a default configuration(s) - in Quarkus, Camel, or Artemis - that is the cause?*

*(The Quarkus app publisher ususally continues to send [although, occasionally will unexpectedly stop sending, for no apparent reason])*

[image: console output from both quarkus and camel apps]

***quarkus app***

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc.jar;

import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.reactive.messaging.Outgoing;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@ApplicationScoped
public class PriceGenerator {

    static int x=0;
    @Outgoing("generated-price")
    public Flowable<Integer> generate() {
        return Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .map(tick -> {
                    System.out.println("PriceGenerator/generate___________________next int: " + x);
                    return x++;
                });
    }    
}
```

***quarkus application.properties***

```
# Configures the AMQP broker credentials.
amqp-username=quarkus
amqp-password=quarkus

# Configure the AMQP connector to write to the `prices` address
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.connector=smallrye-amqp
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.address=prices
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.durable=true
```

***camel route app...***

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc.jar;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.reactive.streams.api.CamelReactiveStreamsService;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.reactive.messaging.Incoming;
import org.reactivestreams.Subscriber;

@Startup
@ApplicationScoped
public class TheRoutes extends RouteBuilder {

    @Inject
    CamelContext ctx;

    @Inject
    CamelReactiveStreamsService crss;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        from("direct:in")
                .streamCaching()
                .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                .log(".........from direct:in - body:  ${body}");
    }

    @Incoming("prices")
    public Subscriber<String> sink() {
        return crss.subscriber("direct:in", String.class);
    }
}
```

***camel application.properties***

```
# Configures the AMQP broker credentials.
amqp-username=quarkus
amqp-password=quarkus

mp.messaging.incoming.prices.address=prices
mp.messaging.incoming.prices.connector=smallrye-amqp
mp.messaging.incoming.prices.durable=true
mp.messaging.incoming.prices.endpoint-uri:direct:in
mp.messaging.incoming.prices.host=localhost
mp.messaging.incoming.prices.port=5672
mp.messaging.incoming.prices.containerId=my-container-id
mp.messaging.incoming.prices.username=quarkus
mp.messaging.incoming.prices.password=quarkus
mp.messaging.incoming.prices.broadcast=true
```

***quarkus app pom.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>aaa.bbb.ccc.jar</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkapp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <properties>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.0</surefire-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <quarkus.version>1.0.0.CR1</quarkus.version>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>    
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemProperties>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemProperties>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                  </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
    <name>quarkapp</name>
</project>
```

***camel app pom.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>aaa.bbb.ccc </groupId>
    <artifactId>camelapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus-plugin.version>1.0.0.CR2</quarkus-plugin.version>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>1.0.0.CR2</quarkus.platform.version>
        <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.1</surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>                 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-timer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-artemis-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-bean</artifactId>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-reactive-streams-operators</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-support-common</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.smallrye.reactive</groupId>
            <artifactId>smallrye-reactive-messaging-camel</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.26</version>
        </dependency>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <systemProperties>
                                        <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                                    </systemProperties>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <name>camelapp</name>
</project>
```

***technologies***

```
java 8
quarkus
apache camel
artemis
maven
```

***misc***

publishing app is based upon the Quark Ampq example: 
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/master/amqp-quickstart/src/main/java/org/acme/quarkus/sample

Comment: It might be possible (just a guess) that an error is sent and the subscription is canceled. Can you check if the Flowable gets an `onCancel` callback and in the capture the `onError` in the subscriber?

Comment: thx, Justin.  I'll try that out.